# Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class:

Tags: spring-boot, maven, swagger, springfox

After I added Swagger dependencies and Swagger Config class I'm getting this error:

```
[main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/mule/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/3.0.0/springfox-swagger2-3.0.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/swagger2/web/Swagger2ControllerWebMvc.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [springfox.documentation.spring.web.OnServletBasedWebApplication]
```

Below is the Swagger Config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(                                            
                    "com.sample.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
                                                
    }
}
```

I added these dependencies in POM file with this Spring boot version. I have some local repositories links also. I had to remove that links. This was running and giving outputs before add Swagger dependencies.

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxx.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hive-api</name>
    <description>API with Hive</description>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292-standalone</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>

</dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: should be `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage( "com.sample.controller"))`  and not `package com.sample.controller;`

Comment: I changed it. It didn't work after that too. I got the same error.

Comment: Is it a web application? don't see `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency...

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web is there in POM file.

Comment: I have added the POM file below. It has some local repositories as well. I had to remove that.

Comment: please remove this as answer, just edit your original question, thx

Comment: @Dirk Deyne I have done that. Thanks

Comment: is using `springfox-boot-starter` is an option have a look add [spring-boot-swagger3](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/spring-boot-swagger3/tree/master) @see the documentation [springfox.github.io](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#spring-boot-applications)

Answer (score 0):

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry

or You can check the problem of using `Swagger` you should not say the `swagger version`

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If it fails , you can refer to this github link : **solved problem**
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932